# C++ efficient parse

Tags: c++, regex, parsing

I am programming some automated test equipment (ATE) and I'm trying to extract the following values out of an example response from the ATE:

```
DCRE? 1, 
DCRE P, 10.3, (pin1)
DCRE F, 200.1, (pin2)
DCRE P, 20.4, (pin3)
```

From each line, I only care about the pin and the measured result value.  So for the case above, I want to store the following pieces of information in a `map<std::string, double> results`;

```
results["pin1"] = 50.3;
results["pin2"] = 30.8;
results["pin3"] = 70.3;
```

I made the following code to parse the response:

```
void parseResultData(map<Pin*, double> &pinnametoresult, string &datatoparse) {
    char *p = strtok((char*) datatoparse.c_str(), " \n");
    string lastread;
    string current;
    while (p) {
        current = p;
        if(current.find('(') != string::npos) {
            string substring = lastread.substr(1); 
            const char* last = substring.c_str();
            double value = strtod(last, NULL);
            unsigned short number = atoi(current.substr(4, current.size()-2).c_str());
            pinnametoresult[&pinlookupmap[number]] = value;
        }
        lastread = p;
        p = strtok(NULL, " \n");
    }
}
```

It works, but it's not very efficient.  Is there a way to make the function more efficient for this specific case?  I don't care about the DCRE or P/F value on each line.  I thought about using Boost regex library, but not sure if that would be more efficient.

Comment: I wouldn't bet on this working. `char const* last = lastread.substr(1).c_str()` creates a (sub-)string, then retrieves the pointer to the internal data, which is stored in `last`. With the trailing semicolon, the substring is destroyed and its internal data release, so you now have a dangling pointer.

Comment: @Ulrich, you're right.  I think I just fixed that bug although now the code is even less efficient.

Comment: Avoid the `substring()`, just use the `strtod(lastread.c_str() + 1)`. ;)

Comment: What does the ATE response look like (a file?)? Why are you reading the entire 'response' to a string and parsing it? Can't you parse it as you're reading it (for example line by line from ifstream).

Comment: @Mustafa Ozturk, actually no.  I'm not getting that response from parsing a file.  If I was, I would not be concerned about performance.  That's actually the response from the tester itself to a retrieve measurement result query.  I interact with the tester through string commands and queries.  Inefficient, I know, but that's what the tester manufacturer decided.

Comment: Is pinlookupmap a map<int, Pin*>?  Why not a vector? `vector<Pin*> pinlookup; Pin* pin = pinlookup[number];`

Comment: Also, if your compiler supports C++11, use a hash (unordered_map) instead of map for pinnametoresult. O(1) vs O(log n) performance.

Comment: Careful, `std::unordered_map` doesn't have to be faster. In all those Big-O statements, constant factors are ignored. There is a certain number of pins where O(1) starts to outperform O(n), but that number is probably not zero. This is similar to `std::vector` outperforming `std::list` for random insertions up to a certain number of elements. If possible, using a `std::vector<Pin*>` should be the fastest way.

Comment: Yeah, I don't know his problem space to comment, however, if he has a few hundred items, this post is entirely unnecessary. If he has millions of items, then I would be surprised if the unordered_map didn't perform better (random access read/write).

Comment: I expect that the number of pins / results per function call will be small...probably on the order of 1-15, median probably somewhere around 3 or 4.  I went with map instead of vector because although I have around 100 pins, the pin combinations tested at any given time will be essentially random...so I can't rely on the vector index.  I care about efficiency here because that function above will be called every time a measurement is taken so very frequently.

Answer (score 2):

In order to make this a bit more efficient, try to avoid copying. In particular, calls to substring, assignments etc can cause havoc on the performance. If you look at your code, you will see that the content of `datatoparse` are repeatedly assigned to `lastread` and `current`, each time with one line less at the beginning. So, on average you copy half of the original string times the number of lines, making just that part an O(n^2) algorithm. This isn't relevant if you have three or four line (not even on 100 lines!) but if you have a few more, performance degrades rapidly.

Try this approach instead:

```
string::size_type p0 = 0;
string::size_type p1 = input.find('\n', p0);
while (p1 != string::npos) {
    // extract the line
    string line = input.substr(p0, p1 - p0);

    // move to the next line
    p0 = p1 + 1;
    p1 = input.find('\n', p0);
}
```

Notes:

- Note that the algorithm still copies all input once, but each line only once, making it O(n).
- Since you have a copy of the line, you can insert `'\0'` as artificial separator in order to give a substring to e.g. `atoi()` or `strtod()`.
- I'm not 100% sure of the order of parameters for `string::find()` and too lazy to look it up, but the idea is to start searching at a certain position. Look at the various overloads of find-like functions.
- When handling a line, search the indices of the parts you need and then extract and parse them.
- If you have line fragments (i.e. a partial line without a newline) at the end, you will have to modify the loop slightly. Create tests!

Comment: Thanks Ulrich, I appreciate your suggestions.  I'll think about my problem a bit more than then post my revised solution using your suggestions.  Actually, for this particular case, I can modify the original string.  If I don't care about the contents of the string beyond extracting my desired data, is there anything wrong with getting the c_str() and then modifying the char array through casting (inserting '\0' as you suggested) to use atoi() and strtod()?  If so, I could do this using no copying.

Comment: I think that should work, although I'd try to avoid casts, they are a warning sign to me that something is wrong. BTW: Did I guess right assuming that you have several hundreds of these lines?

Comment: There's one line per pin so max, I'm thinking I'll only have about 20...maybe 30.  Usually, only 2-4.  However, the function above will be called probably hundreds of thousands or millions of times per test session.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Pin {
    string something; 
    Pin() {}
};

vector<Pin*> pins = { new Pin(), new Pin(), new Pin() };
typedef unordered_map<Pin*, double> CONT_T;

inline bool OfInterest(const string& line) {
    return line.find("(") != string::npos;
}

void parseResultData(CONT_T& pinnametoresult, const string& datatoparse)
{
    istringstream is(datatoparse);
    string line;
    while (getline(is, line)) {
        if (OfInterest(line)) {
            double d = 0.0;
            unsigned int pinid;
            size_t firstComma = line.find(",")+2; // skip space
            size_t secondComma = line.find(",", firstComma);                        
            istringstream is2(line.substr(firstComma, secondComma-firstComma));            
            is2 >> d;
            size_t paren = line.find("(")+4; // skip pin            
            istringstream is3(line.substr(paren, (line.length()-paren)-1));
            is3 >> pinid;
            --pinid;
            Pin* pin = pins[pinid];
            pinnametoresult[pin] = d;            
        }
    }
}



/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    string datatoparse = "DCRE? 1, \n"
            "DCRE P, 10.3, (pin1)\n"
            "DCRE F, 200.1, (pin2)\n"
            "DCRE P, 20.4, (pin3)\n";


    CONT_T results;
    parseResultData(results, datatoparse);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This should solve the performance issues, at least it should give a good boost to performance.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my final result.  Does not involve any copying, but it will destroy the string.

```
void parseResultData3(map<std::string, double> &pinnametoresult, std::string &datatoparse) {
    char* str = (char*) datatoparse.c_str();
    int length = datatoparse.size();
    double lastdouble = 0.0;
    char* startmarker = NULL; //beginning of next pin to parse

    for(int pos = 0; pos < length; pos++, str++) {
        if(str[0] == '(') {
            startmarker = str + 1;
            //get previous value
            bool triggered = false;
            for(char* lookback = str - 1; ; lookback--) {
                if(!triggered && (isdigit(lookback[0]) || lookback[0] == '.')) {
                    triggered = true;
                    *(lookback + 1) = '\0';
                }
                else if(triggered && (!isdigit(lookback[0]) && lookback[0] != '.')) {
                    lastdouble = strtod(lookback, NULL);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else if(startmarker != NULL) {
            if(str[0] == ')') {
                str[0] = '\0';
                pinnametoresult[startmarker] = lastdouble;
                startmarker = NULL;
            }
            if(str[0] == ',') {
                str[0] = '\0';
                pinnametoresult[startmarker] = lastdouble;
                startmarker = str + 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't like the fact that you're casting away the constness of the c ptr returned by c_str() at all. You said you're retrieving 3-4 pins worth of data each function call (by my estimate, roughly 128 bytes). On a 64 bit machine, with DDR DRAM, you can copy 128 bytes from one memory location to another in a very, very short time. Unless you're reading from hardware at a very high rate, I cannot see how you would be justified in doing this.